# How to define new Unit using NumericPrelude

Tags: haskell

I need some kind of unit to avoid mixing things like quantities, volume prices etc... I don't really care of the physical dimenseion but I need to isolate them from each other. I've seen a couple 'unit' packages on cabal but they seems either not good enough or to heavy for the job.

As the problem is simple , I thought I could just do it on my own and just create a few new types deriving Num.

The good stuff with deriving Num is you can add number together, and *cast* them automatically via `fromInteger`. The downside is you can also multiply them together which I don't want. Multiplying  price by a price is not a price.

So I start thinking, that's is a shame that the `Num` class includes `*` where it's not really necessary. Maybe I can rewrite my own `Num` class so I can reuse `+` form my new types. Thinking of that I stumble on [NumericPrelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) which seems to be pretty much how the numeric prelude should have been. Moreover, It has some *unit* capabilities but the documentation is terse. Do you know how I can use it to basically setup the following units :

- Quantity
- Price
- Amount = Quantity*Price

## Update

For people wondering why quantity is not dimensionless and why `Price` is different from `Amount`, the reason are :

- `Quantity` refers to a number of pieces, ex `1 Potato`. Multiply `Quantity` doesn't make sense (what's a Potato^2), however `Quantity` is an (additive) `Monoid`.
- `Price` is in fact `Currency/Potato`. Adding `Price` makes sense, but it's not a `Monoid` because I can't reduce a list of prices. I need a average weighted by quantities.
- `Amount` is `Currency` and it's an (additive) `Monoid`.
  I don't want to mix up prices and amounts for that reason : I can `mappend` a list of `Amount` but I don't want to do so with `Price`. To get an average price I have to `mconcat` `[(Quantity, Amount)]` and make the division.

To reformulate my question, how can achieve this using the `NumericPrelude` package or another one ?

Comment: Have you considered [vector-space](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.8.7/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html)? It gives you much exactly the interface needed for making just some physical quantities additive and constant-scalable, without completely changing _everything_ like the numerical-prelude does. Of course you'll need to write `^+^` instead of `+`, but I don't think that should be much of an issue.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this package. There are too many package and cabal and SO is apparently not the place to ask for recommendation ;-). I'll have a look

Comment: Can you explain why Quantity*Price is Amount and not Price?

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory. If Volume * Quantity is Volume, then Quantity is dimensionless and Amount is Price.

Comment: @n.m I know.  I might seems fancy but there is a reason for it. Moreover I can do it easily if create my own `Multiply` class so I have no reason to not do it. see my update

Comment: You can try to eliminate contradictions from your method by inventing more and more ad-hoc rules, or you can try a method that is proven to be working and contradiction-free. Guess on which path you will find more support.

Comment: @n.m: Ok, so what would be the contradiction-free method ? If add a 'Volume/Potato' I don't see any contraction.

Comment: Well the volume thing is the main contradiction. If you want only quantities of potato, you might be able to get away with this change. Otherwise you need many different kinds of quantity (potatoes are not camels) and many different kinds of price (price per potato is not price per camel, you cannot add those) and many different kinds of the volume-per-unit thing. Now imagine you need to multiply and divide different quantities (20 boxes * 20 candies per box * 12 boxes per carton * 800 cartons per truck ...) and it looks like it would be easier to use a generic package than to roll your own.

Comment: @n.m: exactly. I want to use a generic package and I was thinking using numeric-prelude, which the point of my question. I remove `Volume` from my question, has it's unnecessary here, and I have only Potato which I is why I called it Quantity, but I would call it Potata if you really insist.

Comment: A consistent system of units has a basis from which you create new units. For example, in the SI system of units, the basis is [K, A, Mol, s, m, kg, cd], and every unit you can have is created from a combination of those (specifically, from multiplication and inverse). In your case your basis is [Quantity, Price]: a very simple system. Potentially, quantity should be indexed by the underlying *object*, so you would have [Quantity obj, Price] as your basis. Take a look at [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-0.13/docs/Numeric-Units-Dimensional-Extensible.html)

Comment: I was also going to suggest dimensional.

Comment: Can anyone do proper answer and get me started with `dimensional` please ?